# Simple GROK pattern for JAVA

Tags: grok

Its weird that GROK pattern is not parsing the string :

```
org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.loadGlobalSettings

%{JAVACLASS:class}\.%{JAVAMETHOD:method}
```

I see compile error. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that JAVAMETHOD is not found, I didn't have time to check if was removed or what's going on with it, but [here you can see how it is done](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/java)

So a quick work around is to create your own custom pattern

```
JAVAMETHOD (?:(<(?:cl)?init>)|[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_0-9]*)
```

After that this works

[image: example]

Comment: But I see even in our application the same issue of not parsing the JAVAMETHOD is happening even though the pattern exists

Comment: For some reason is not loading this pattern, also this fails in the grok debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%{GREEDYDATA:class}.%{WORD:method}
```

As you can see [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) it works.

Comment: Yes that works but I want JAVAMETHOD to work as that's more precise to use :)